# Change text color of search hint in actionbar using support library

Tags: android, textview, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I want to change the text color of search view hint, but I tried in many ways with no success.
Like in this post: [Changing action bar searchview hint text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791388/changing-action-bar-searchview-hint-text-color)

I'm using Appcompat, support library of actionbar.

I tried this with null pointer return:

```
AutoCompleteTextView searchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.abs__search_src_text);
searchView.findViewById(R.id.abs__search_src_text);
searchText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
searchText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Wrong id for the AutoCompleteTextView, I guess. Unless you use a custom Action Bar Search widget. Try smth. like the following:

```
((EditText)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text))
            .setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

Comment: Using `android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text` works versus using `R.id.search_src_text`.

Comment: thanks. For androidx you can also use androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18012584/2087208) too:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.item_search);
mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
mSearchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.text));
SearchAutoComplete searchAutoComplete = (SearchAutoComplete) mSearchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
searchAutoComplete.setHintTextColor(mRes.getColor(android.R.color.white));
searchAutoComplete.setTextSize(14);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code:

`getResources().getColor(R.color.white)`

it is possible that an alert saying that `getColor(int) is deprecated` appears. This is because from api 23, a new `getColor()` method was added to the ContextCompat.

So just use the following:

```
((EditText) searchView.findViewById (android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text))
                     .setHintTextColor (ContextCompat.getColor (getBaseContext(), Color.WHITE));
```

It worked for me.