# How to use a custom view in app:actionViewClass

Tags: android, searchview

i have a menu item like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search_toolBar"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Instead of using `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` can i use a customized search view.

Comment: Would you please elaborate this a little more? **can i use a customized search view**

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14137141/8872691) what you are looking for?